# Determine whether parsed varargin input should be passed as an argument vs. parsing within each function

Tags: matlab, function, parsing, input

I have a set of functions that takes a cell array of tables and plots data from each table as a subplot on a figure.  I have been learning to use the `inputParser` class to handle `varargin` inputs, and have that here. The optional parameters are for choosing plot type (`plot` or `bar`) and for choosing the names of the variables to plot from the input tables.

In my scenario, the inputs need to be passed along about 3 functions deep, so I'm wondering about best practices for doing this. In my current setup, the outermost function (`main`) takes a `varargin` input and parses the inputs by assigning defaults and such.  Then I'm wondering, when it comes time to pass these inputs to the next function, is it best to pass the `parsedInputs` data Results struct down the line, or is it better to have the next function also take a `varargin` argument and to repeat the parsing process again? I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is. My code is below. The main script for test purposes looks as follows:

```
% RUN TEST CASE
Tables{1} = table([1 2 3]' , [6 7 8]', 'VariableNames', {'diam', 'length'});
Tables{2} = table([1 2 6]' , [6 9 2]', 'VariableNames', {'diam', 'length'});
Tables{3} = table([3 9 11]', [7 4 1]', 'VariableNames', {'diam', 'length'});
main(Tables);
```

The main function takes a (required) cell array of tables (`Tables`) and variable argument parameters, such as `'xVariable'`, `'yVariable'`, `'plotType'`.

```
function main(Tables, varargin)%PlotParams, DICTS)
  % parse inputs
  parsedInputs = parse_plot_inputs(Tables, varargin);

  % create figure of subplots
  figure;  
  make_subplots_from_tables(parsedInputs);
end
```

A `parse_plot_inputs` function takes care of the default value assignment, etc.:

```
function parsedInputs = parse_plot_inputs(Tables, vararginList)
% input parser function for this specific plotting case
  p = inputParser;
  addRequired(p,  'Tables', @iscell);
  addParameter(p, 'xVariable', 'diam');
  addParameter(p, 'yVariable', 'length');
  addParameter(p, 'plotType', 'plot');
  parse(p, Tables, vararginList{:});
  parsedInputs = p;
end
```

`make_subplots_from_tables` then loops through the cell array of tables, and calls `plot_special` to plot each of them on its own subplot.

```
function make_subplots_from_tables(parsedInputs) 

  % unpack parsed inputs
  Tables = parsedInputs.Results.Tables;

  % plot each table as a subplot
  numTables = length(Tables);
  for i = 1:numTables      
      subplot(numTables, 1, i); hold on;
      plot_special(Tables{i}, parsedInputs)
  end
end
```

`plot_special` is the "base" function in this scenario that calls the MATLAB plot functions:

```
function plot_special(T, parsedInputs)

  % unpack parsed inputs
  xVariable = parsedInputs.Results.xVariable;
  yVariable = parsedInputs.Results.yVariable;
  plotType  = parsedInputs.Results.plotType;

  % plot single table on one plot
  xVals = T.(xVariable);
  yVals = T.(yVariable);
  switch plotType
    case 'plot'
      plot(xVals, yVals, '-x');
    case 'bar'
      bar(xVals, yVals);
    otherwise
      error('invalid plot type');
  end
end
```

I am unsure whether this is the best method for taking in arguments and for using them in subsequent functions.  This method works, although I'm not sure that it's the best practice, nor the most flexible, for example, considering the scenario when I would like to use plot_special on its own, and would like to be able to pass it arguments for `xVariable`, `yVariable`, etc. if need be.  Given that it is currently dependent on the `parsedInputs` list from the `main` function, that wouldn't be doable.  However, I'm unsure what another way to define it would be. I considered having an `if` statement built in along with a `varargin` input argument that checks whether the varargin is an already-parsed struct, or if it's getting the variables directly and needs to call the `parse_plot_inputs` itself to get things working.  Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "best" method, it all depends on circumstances. What you are doing is fine if the functions that take an `inputParser` object are private sub-functions. If they are generic functions that should work independently, they should have their own argument parsing. One thing you could do, given that you want `plot_special` to be a stand-alone function, is as follows:

```
function main(Tables, varargin)
  figure;  
  make_subplots_from_tables(Tables, varargin{:});
end

function make_subplots_from_tables(Tables, varargin) 
  % plot each table as a subplot
  numTables = length(Tables);
  for i = 1:numTables      
      subplot(numTables, 1, i); hold on;
      plot_special(Tables{i}, varargin{:})
  end
end

function plot_special(T, varargin)
  % parse `varargin` to yield `xVariable`, `yVariable`, `plotType`
  % plot single table on one plot
end
```

This way you do the parameter parsing only where necessary, although it is done once for each table plotted, rather than only once for the whole graph. This is probably a very minor issue though, since parameter parsing is not nearly as expensive as plotting.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. I think that method definitely works best for making things streamlined.  Assuming though, as you mentioned, that none of these are private functions, is it appropriate practice to test within each function whether `varargin` is an inputParser object, and if not, to parse the `varargin` inputs using some function that assigns all the necessary parameters?